# How do you truncate extra decimals from BigDecimal

Tags: java

I'm building a service that uses a currency converter and forwards the BigDecimal amount to another service. Sometimes, the conversion rate makes it so that the converted amount has close to 34 decimal places, which the downstream service does not accept.

Is there a way to simply truncate (not round) the BigDecimal.  So, for example, if the converted amount is 1.23456789 I want neither 1.24, nor 1.3, nor 1.20, or anything of that sort.  I simply want to get rid of the decimals that appear after 4.  So what I want is 1.23.

I saw a lot of questions on SO related to this, but they all rounded the BigDecimal in some way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RoundingMode.DOWN` effectively truncates your decimal values:

Javadoc says:

> Rounding mode to round towards zero. Never increments the digit prior
>   to a discarded fraction (i.e., truncates). Note that this rounding
>   mode never increases the magnitude of the calculated value.

```
BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(10.2384235254634623524);
System.out.println(dec.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN));
```

Will give:

```
10.23
```

Comment: Yes, DOWN seems better in this case.  Since FLOOR will make -1.5041 to -1.51 thus changing the first two decimal places, which I do not want.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it aligns to its doc too

Answer (score 4):

BigDecimal provides RoundingMode, which you need here is RoundingMode.FLOOR,

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.234567").setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR)); // 1.23
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.236567").setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR)); // 1.23
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try treating it like a string

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#0.##").format(new BigDecimal("1.23456789")));
```

Answer (score 0):

`BigDecimal` also provides `Rounding Modes`. Try this

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(2.2964556655);
System.out.println(bd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN));
```

Comment: I am trying to set the value to floor value of "10.00" than "10.23". It's just been impossible with the range of RoundingMode.FLOOR, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN. 
For example I have amount of $518.00 in twelve equal installments of $43.17
I would like the $43.17 * 12 == 518.00 but it shows up as 518.04